# Ford focus - where is this oil coming from please?

Tags: ford, oil, leak

[image]

Went to look at buying a Focus yesterday 1.5tdci 2016 57k on the clock. I noticed an oil leak (see photo). Does anyone have an idea where it might be leaking from? Does it look expensive to fix?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That could be from either of two sources:

1. most likely, this is from the oil that is in the incoming air to the turbo, from the crankcase ventilation system. The outer housing is bolted to the backing plate and the clamping force may not be even around the periphery.
2. the high pressure oil feed - that banjo bolt is usually sealed with copper washers and may just need fresh washers and tightening.

It does not look that serious, but cleaning and further testing will confirm that.

Comment: Thanks Mike. The car is my sister's company car that we have the option of buying as she is getting a new one. Please can I ask would it put you off buying the car if you weren't mechanically minded and would need a garage to sort it? Thanks

Comment: Consider an AA or RAC inspection or do you have a friendly garage? How was the company car serviced? Many can be well-looked after...

Comment: If it’s always run well an needed minimal mechanical intervention then I would consider purchasing it; that leak is incredibly small, the amount of oil needed to make a creeping stain on a hot engine part like that is probably less than 1 millilitre